# How to handle old versions of Room Database or how to mange fallback for specific versions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, database-migration, fallback

**How we can manage old database versions.**
 For example **version = 1**  **version= 2** both are my old version, **current version=10**. There is too many changes in **version 9,10.**
 in this case i want to clear database for **version 1,2** if they update to **version= 9 or 10**

**or**
 **how can we write fallback for specific versions?**

Answer (score 0):

**For managing fallback for specific versions or for all version Room has some method by which we can manage fallback.**

1- **fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(int versions...)**

- **it is allowed to destructively recreate database tables from specific**
- starting schema versions.
- This functionality is the same as that provided by
- {@link #fallbackToDestructiveMigration()}, except that this method allows the
- specification of a set of schema versions for which destructive recreation is allowed.
- Using this method is preferable to {@link #fallbackToDestructiveMigration()} if you want
- to allow destructive migrations from some schema versions while still taking advantage
- of exceptions being thrown due to unintentionally missing migrations.
- Note: No versions passed to this method may also exist as either starting or ending
- versions in the {@link Migration}s provided to {@link #addMigrations(Migration...)}. If a
- version passed to this method is found as a starting or ending version in a Migration, an
- exception will be thrown.

  ```
     instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, DbHelper.class, "DatabaseName")
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_4_5,MIGRATION_5_6)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(1,2,3)
                .addCallback(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        super.onCreate(db);
                        try {

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).build();
  ```

2- **fallbackToDestructiveMigration()**

- Allows Room to destructively recreate database tables if {@link Migration}s that would
- migrate old database schemas to the latest schema version are not found.
- When the database version on the device does not match the latest schema version, Room
- runs necessary {@link Migration}s on the database.
- If it cannot find the set of {@link Migration}s that will bring the database to the
- current version, it will throw an {@link IllegalStateException}.
- **You can call this method to change this behavior to re-create the database instead of
  crashing.**
- If the database was create from an asset or a file then Room will try to use the same
- file to re-create the database, otherwise this will delete all of the data in the
- database tables managed by Room.

```
     instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, DbHelper.class, "DatabaseName")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                            super.onCreate(db);
                            try {
                              
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).build();
```